# Android Espresso GridView scroll to each item and perform a click on them

Tags: android, gridview, android-espresso

I have a GridView loaded with data, and some items in the grid are "group" items
that contain a different set of data. The GridView can scroll if there is
a lot of data.

On some devices the GridView has three columns and on others there are only two columns depending on the device screen width.

What I need to test is to scroll to a particular(with text) item in the grid, open it and then close it(back button=simpleClick). Then scroll to a second item with a particular text and open and then close it(back button=simpleClick).

I have tried several approaches with swipes, and then performing clicks
on them, but this approach fails as you need to know exactly how many
swipes/scrolls to perform before I can click to open the item group - device specific which is bad. Also performing too many scrolls than what is required to reach the bottom of the screen seems to slowdown the test !!quite!! a bit.

```
   private void scrollDown() {
        Log.d(TAG, "scrollDown: ");
        onView(withId(R.id.main_grid))
                .perform(swipeUp());
    }

    private void scrollUp() {
        Log.d(TAG, "scrollUp: ");
        onView(withId(R.id.main_grid))
                .perform(swipeDown());

    }

private void clickOn(final String text) {

    onView(withText(new Matcher<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object item) {

                if (item instanceof String) {
                    if (((String) item).contains(text))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void describeMismatch(Object item, Description mismatchDescription) {

            }

            @Override
            public void _dont_implement_Matcher___instead_extend_BaseMatcher_() {

            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {

            }
    }))
        .perform(click());
}
```

I have tried this as well, but focus gets set to each Item
but as it reaches the end of the screen, one needs to scroll manually
on the device - it does not scroll the screen.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 20; i++) {
               onData(anything())
                       .inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.main_grid), isDisplayed()))
                       .atPosition(i)
                       .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

I have also tried using the onData which I cannot get to succeed(compile/build),
as I am using a CursorLoader and a ResourceCursorAdapter.

Any Example to solve my test case would great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use onData statement to avoid problems with scrolling in GridView. You can take a look at example here - http://droidtestlab.com/adapterView.html

But in your case you will have android.database.Cursor interface as a parameter to onData. Something like this (here you specify that you want to wait for data in GridView where first column is equal "VALUE" and then click at this record):

```
onData(allOf(is(new BoundedMatcher<Object, Cursor>(Cursor.class) {
    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Cursor cursor) {
        return cursor.getString(0).equals("VALUE");
    }
}))).inAdapterView(withId(<ADAPTER_ID>)).perform(click());
```